# Problems with javascript date with different time zones

Tags: javascript, c#, json, datetime, json.net

I have an object with a DateTime property (get;set;) which is inside a collection (List) in C#. This property holds the value of DateTime.MinValue (01/01/0001 12:00:00 AM).

I am using the Newtsonsoft.Json.Net library to serialize my collection of objects as JSON like this

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionValues,
    new JsonConverter[] { new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter() })
```

The converted output of my datetime property is `new Date(-62135578800000)` which in UTC-5 gives me a date of **"Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00 GMT-0500"**, but doing some tests in other time zones my serialization is still `new Date(-62135578800000)` but output in javascript is quite different **"Sun Dec 31 0 22:00:00 GMT-0700"**

I ran this test on the [w3schools site](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FERA7SZCCJB6) changing the time zone of my computer.

How can I do to return always the value of **"Mon Jan 01 1 00:00:00"** no matter what time zone when my property server side is DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: Why?  The two times are the same.  First is EST while 2nd is MST.  Why are you comparing strings then you should compare DateTime.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I am not comparing strings. I just put the output resulting from new Date(-62135578800000). In my client side code I am working directly with DateTime type but if my users PC time zone change the app gives a different output because of the wrong year in javascript.

Comment: That is exactly how it should work when in different time zones.  Converting to UTC is not going to solve issue, because it is going to push every into the next year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [DateTimeZoneHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDateTimeZoneHandling.htm) setting. I suggest you to always serialize date in UTC to avoid such collisions:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(collectionValues, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
});
```